# Import of special characters & NA's of csv into SAS does not work

Tags: r, import, character-encoding, sas, export

I have a csv file with many "NA" values and with special characters such as ä, ö or ß. I want to import this csv file into `SAS` via `proc import`, but unfortunately I have two problems:

1) The NA's are read as characters and not as missing values

2) Special characters are changed automatically into something like @!+-~

When I import the csv into `R` I am able to solve both problems with the encoding "UTF-8" - NA's are recognized to be missings and special characters are displayed correctly. My idea was to export the file from `R` as dbf file and import this dbf file into `SAS`. This procedure solves the problem with the NA's, but however, special characters are again displayed in a wrong way. I also tried different encodings in SAS, but that also did not work. Any helpd is highly appreciated!

Comment: What version of SAS are your using? What encoding is your SAS session using?

Comment: Thanks for your response Tom, based on the answer of r.user.05apr I was able to fix my problem already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a data step instead of proc import. It could look like:

```
Data MyCSV;
  Infile "C:\MyName\ImportData.CSV"
         Delimiter="," LRecL=1000 DSD Missover Firstobs=2; * Firstobs=2 to delete col-names;
  Informat qty_txt $9. ; * 9 .. length in characters;
  If qty_txt ^= "NA" Then qty=Input(qty_txt,Best15.); Drop qty_txt;
Run;
```

(If you're exporting from R set na="." in write.csv.)

Regarding the special characters problem, Define the variable as character in the informat-statement should work.